# Eclipse XHTML Visual Editor

Tags: eclipse, xhtml, eclipse-plugin, rcp

All,

I am looking for an visual editor(could be open source) for XHTML to place it in my Eclipse RCP application. Please suggest on the same

Thanks,
Chandra M

Comment: what do you mean by visual editor - a wysyswig editor? Or just one that you see the result of your code?